# Вывод содержимого массива по клику на объект Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js

Уважаемые сенсеи.Пишу SPA на Vue.JS.
Есть список объектов,содержание которых берется из массива(заголовок,дискрипшн,фото и тд)
Как сделать так,что при клике на один из этих объектов в другом блоке отображалось содержимое именно этого объекта?

Comment: У вас что-то есть из кода? добавьте свои наработки, а мы уже посмотрим и допишим их

Comment: Я пишу при помощи шаблона Vue CLI и Vuetify.
примерно так:
* код вывода объектов из массива (выводится только заголовок,дискрипшн и фото*
* код вывода объекта по клику на объект сверху (выводятся все объекты из массива*
* массив:
фото:
заголовок:
дискрипшн:
цена:
локация:
тип:
категория: *